# How to filter and retrieve multiple entities at the same time?

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8 country module and have over 100 countries. I've enabled all related modules for Drupal 8 web services to operate.

My task is that I need to retrieve say 30 specific countries filtered by say `status = true`. All the examples I see point to GET retrieving a single item, for example the url below works... (`http://localhost/truemandate/entity/country/NG?_format=json`). But how do I retreive multiple items at same time using REST? I know JSON-API does this easily using filters - but the output of JSON-API seems too verbose for my requirements.

I've also heard you must create a view before REST can return multiple entities. Not sure the impact of this on performance. I also have about 20 other custom entities which I need to be able to retrieve multiple items from all at once(using my mobile app).

Should I use REST or JSON-API for this? Please I'm open to suggestions on best way to expose a fast, well-built country list web service

Comment: `I've also heard you must create a view before REST can return multiple entities` Correct, your only options are either via [JSON-API URL](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/fetching-resources-get) or Views. As far as performance is concerned, you'll be fine, View gets cached.

Comment: Many thanks buddy, that answer was quick!! But pls which of the 2 approaches would be best considering my requirements? Also heard that json-api requires the entity's uuid not entity ID. So can't be used with custom entities that do not have a uuid field?

Comment: You only need the `uuid` in the URL if you want to see a specific entity, not list of various entities like in your case.

Comment: I am a bit confused when you say REST and JSON API. The best practice is to install JSON API module, which is included in the core now, where it is a replacement to Views module in the headless Drupal approach. You can use filtering and include params to have the data you want. Here is a link to the documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/jsonapi-module/filtering